# No carga Business Component Gx17U9

Tags: genexus

Con Gx17 U9 tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy generando Java Web, en un WebPanel con la propiedad

```
Web User Experience = Previous versions compatible
```

Realizo lo siguiente

```
Event Enter
    &transactionBC.Load(&Varible)
EndEvent
```

En pantalla tengo los elementos de ese BC, pero no carga ningun valor. Esto si estaria funcionando en upgrades enteriores, como por ejemplo Gx17U4

Es un problema del upgrade? Alguna solucion?

Comment: Este problema me sucede en varios webpanel, por lo que es "complicado" modificar codigo o propiedades (Smooth)

Comment: Si pruebas hardcodeando el código del registro, por ejemplo &transactionBC.Load(1), ¿te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo, ya sea hardcode o variable no muestra los valores en los componentes del BC en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Por casualidad no tienes la master page con Web user interface en "Smooth"? Para que funcione bien tanto la Master Page como los objetos tienen que tener esa propiedad igual.

Comment: Ese Web Panel no tiene master page, justamente lo prepare para mostrar el problema. Toda nuestra KB (+1200 webpanel) esta desarrollada de esta manera y funcionando con Gx17U4